# Average value and sum of strings for each day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 3 columns. I am using python / pandas.

```
     date         id         my_value1      my_value2
0    31.07.20     128909      0.098333      positive
1    31.07.20     128914      0.136364      positive
3    31.07.20     853124     -0.025000      negative
4    30.07.20     123456     -1.000000      neutral
...
```

The first column contains the date (can be parsed to any other form) with days from 06.02.20 to 31.07.20 with some days missing. As you can see each day appears several times.

The column my_value1 contains a float number between 1 and -1.

The column my_value2 contains either the string "postive", "negative" or "neutral".

What I want is a new dataframe containing the average value of "my_value1" for each day and the sum of each value of "my_value2" which could look like this:

```
     date         average_value1     sum_positive     sum_negative     sum_neutral
0    31.07.20      0.1               1532             2153             5321
1    30.07.20      0.2               2153             5321             1532
3    29.07.20     -0.3               1234             1234             1234
...
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the original DataFrame's index is unimportant, you could do

```
encoded_df = pd.get_dummies(df, prefix="", prefix_sep="", columns=["my_value2"])
output = encoded_df.groupby("date").agg(
    average_value1 = pd.NamedAgg("my_value1", "mean"),
    sum_positive = pd.NamedAgg("positive", "sum"),
    sum_negative = pd.NamedAgg("negative", "sum"),
    sum_neutral = pd.NamedAgg("neutral", "sum")
).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
       date  average_value1  sum_positive  sum_negative  sum_neutral
0  30.07.20       -1.000000             0             0            1
1  31.07.20        0.069899             2             1            0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I will go:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
# read data
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""    date         id         my_value1      my_value2
0    31.07.20     128909      0.098333      positive
1    31.07.20     128914      0.136364      positive
3    31.07.20     853124     -0.025000      negative
4    30.07.20     123456     -1.000000      neutral
"""), sep='\s+')

df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
# obtain daily average
df_avg = df.resample('D').my_value1.mean().to_frame('average')
# obtain the counts
df_cnt = df.resample('D').my_value2.value_counts()
df_cnt = df_cnt.to_frame()
df_cnt = df_cnt.unstack()
df_cnt = df_cnt.droplevel(level=0, axis=1)
# join the two dataframes
df_avg.join(df_cnt)
# The desired output
    average negative    neutral positive
date                
2020-07-30  -1.000000   NaN 1.0 NaN
2020-07-31  0.069899    1.0 NaN 2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tmp1 = df.groupby('date')['my_value1'].mean().to_frame('average_value1')

tmp2 = (
    df.groupby(['date', 'my_value2'])
        ['my_value1'].sum()
        .unstack()
        [['positive', 'negative', 'neutral']]
)
tmp2.columns = 'sum_' + tmp2.columns

result = tmp1.join(tmp2)
```

Comment: Looks like its working, but instead of the sum as a number the column contains a long string of e.g. "PositivePositivePositivePositivePositive...". Do you know a quick fix for that?

Comment: I changed it to upper case since its actually uppercase in my data. But all the other column names fit.